# What is the equivalent of Java's protected attributes in Nim?

Tags: oop, inheritance, protected, nim-lang

I was playing around with OOP in Nim and when I tried to implement inheritance between two Nim types in different files, I encounter the following problem, when importing a type from other file could not find a way to implement protected attributes.

In the following block of code, it is represented the Java code.

```
class Vehicle {
  protected String brand = "Ford";        // Vehicle attribute
}

class Car extends Vehicle {
  private String modelName = "Mustang";    // Car attribute
  
   public String getName() {
       return this.brand + " " + this.modelName;
   }
}

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Create a myCar object
    var myCar = new Car();
    System.out.println(myCar.getName());
  }
}
```

Is there anything similar to protected attributes in Nim?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no equivalency, Nim only has exported and unexported fields. So if you want to access the `brand` you need to use `*` on the field. Though you could likely emulate the same logic as protected using the following 'pattern'.

As such

```
# vehicles.nim
type Vehicle* = object of RootObj # Or ref object if you want runtime polymorphism
    brand*: string

proc init*(vehicle: var Vehicle) =
  vehicle.brand = "Ford"

# main
import vehicles

type Car = object of Vehicle
  modelName*: string

proc init*(car: var Car) =
  Vehicle(car).init()
  car.modelName = "Mustang"

proc name*(car: Car): string =
  result = car.name
  result.add " "
  result.add car.brand

let car = (var temp = Car(); temp.init(); temp) # Make a constructor to abstract this away I guess
echo car.name
```

Comment: It is also worth noting that fields not marked with "*" are analogous to private fields in Java.